# Chat app using socket.io and Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express

I am new to Node.js and facing problem using socket.id to identify logged in users on the client side using email id and password which is verified from a table on server side and if verified, user socket.id is used to send a username to that client.

When two users login, they can chat with unique usernames, but when the chat page is refreshed both usernames get changed to the username of the second login (i.e. the user who logged in later). Please help.

Here is my code:

```
server.js

    var express = require('express')
    , app = express()
    , http = require('http')
    , server = http.createServer(app)
    , Twit = require('twit')
    , io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
    , os = require('os')
    , open = require('open')
    , bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    , connect = require('connect')
    , mysql = require("mysql");

    var clients = {};

    server.listen(9383,'192.168.1.3');

    app.get('/loginstyle.css', function (req, res) {
      res.sendfile(__dirname + '/loginstyle.css');
    });

    app.get('/loginme', function (req, res) {
      res.sendfile(__dirname + '/loginmysql.html');
    });

    app.get('/option', function (req, res) {
      res.sendfile(__dirname + '/option.html');
    });

    app.get('/chat', function (req, res) {
      res.sendfile(__dirname + '/chat.html');
    });

    app.post('/valid', function (req, res) {

      var username=req.body.email;
      var password=req.body.pass;

      var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        "hostname": "localhost",
        "user": "root",
        "password": "vk123",
        "database": "login"
      });

      connection.connect();

      connection.query('SELECT * FROM id WHERE email=? AND password=?', [username,password], function(err, rows){

        if (err){
          throw err;
        }else{
              var name1=rows[0].name;

              io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
                clients[socket.id] = socket;
                clients[socket.id].emit('name', name1); // username is sent to client
               });

              res.redirect('http://192.168.1.3:9383/chat');
        }
      });

    connection.end();
    });


      io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
        socket.on('chat message', function(name,msg){

          console.log(msg);    
          io.emit('chatmessage',name,msg);
        });
      });

client.html



<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body background="/bgimage.jpg">
        <div class="chat"></div>    

        <form style="bottom:10px; position:fixed; padding-left: 100px">
            <input type="text" class="msg" style="width:1000px; height:30px"></input>
            <button type="submit" class="enter" style="padding-left:0px; height:35px; background-color:skyblue">Send</button>
        </form>

        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.3:9383');
            var username;
            var chatmsg=[];

            socket.on('name', function(name){
                username=name;
                console.log(username);
            });


        $('.enter').bind("click",function(){
                chatmsg.push({chatname:username, msgtext:($('.msg').val())});
                socket.emit('chat message',username,$('.msg').val() );
                $('.msg').val('');
                return false;
            });

            socket.on('chatmessage', function(name,msg){

                var block= $("<div class='message'> </div>");
                if(msg.length){
                    var messenger= $("<div style='color:green;font-weight:bold;background-color:floralwhite'> </div>");
                    messenger.append(name);
                    block.append(messenger);
                    var text=$("<div style='padding:3px;background-color:floralwhite'></div>");
                    text.append(msg);
                    block.append(text);
                    block.append($("<div style='padding:10px;background-color:transparent'></div>"));
                    $('.chat').append(block);
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It seems like `io.sockets.on('connection', ...` should be something more specific to socket associated with `req`, not something global for all sockets.

Answer (score 0):

Index.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var _mysql = require('mysql');

var HOST = 'localhost';
var PORT = 3306;
var MYSQL_USER = 'root';
var MYSQL_PASS = '';
var DATABASE = 'library';
var TABLE = 'chat';

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


 io.on('connection', function(socket){

    var mysql = _mysql.createConnection({
            host: HOST,
            port: PORT,
            user: MYSQL_USER,
            password: MYSQL_PASS,
        });

        mysql.query('use ' + DATABASE);

      socket.on('chat message', function(from, msg){         
         if(from != 'System'){
             io.emit('chat message', from, msg);
         }              
      });  

      socket.on('notifyUser', function(user){
        io.emit('notifyUser', user);
      });  

    socket.on('saveUser', function(from, msg){      
        mysql.query("insert into "+ TABLE +" (send_from, send_message) values ('"+from+"','"+msg+"')",
        function selectCb(err, results, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
        });     
    });  

    socket.on('display', function(){
        mysql.query("select * from "+ TABLE +" order by (chat_id) asc ",
        function selectCb(err, rows, fields) {
            io.emit('display', rows);   
            //console.log(rows);
        });
    });
});

http.listen(81, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Index.html

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>   
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      $(document).ready(function(){
          var data_name = sessionStorage.getItem('name');
          if(data_name){
              var name = data_name;
              $('#user').val(name);
          }else{          
              var name = makeid();
              var hello = sessionStorage.setItem('name', name);
              $('#user').val(name);
          }
          socket.emit('chat message', 'System', '<b>' + name + '</b> has joined the discussion');

         $('form').submit(function(){   
            var from = $('#user').val();
            var message  = $('#m').val();
            if(message != '') {
                socket.emit('chat message', from, message);
                $('#m').val('').focus();
            }           
            return false;
          });

          socket.on('chat message', function(from, msg){ 

            var me = $('#user').val();

            if(from == me){ 
                socket.emit('saveUser', me, msg);
            }
            var color = (from == me) ? 'green' : '#009afd';
            var from = (from == me) ? 'Me' : from;
            $('#messages').append('<li><b style="color:' + color + '">' + from + '</b>: ' + msg + '</li>');



          });

          socket.emit('display');

          socket.on('display', function(results){ 
            var me = $('#user').val();  
            $('#messages').html('');                
            $.each( results, function( key, value ) {
               var from = value.send_from;
               var color = (from == me) ? 'green' : '#009afd';
               var from = (from == me) ? 'Me' : from;

               $('#messages').append('<li><b style="color:' + color + '">' + from + '</b>: ' + value.send_message + '</li>');            
            });

          });

          socket.on('notifyUser', function(user){
              var me = $('#user').val();
              if(user != me) {
                $('#notifyUser').text(user + ' is typing ...');
              }
              setTimeout(function(){ $('#notifyUser').text(''); }, 10000);
          });


      });

        function makeid() {
          var text = "";
          var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

          for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ ) {
            text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
          }
          return text;
        }
    </script>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages">
    <?php       
        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','library');

    ?>
    </ul>
    <form action="">
      <input type="hidden" id="user"  />
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```